# solve for x in the following Quadratic equations

Tags: quadratics

I am not able to solve this problem for my son. Is ther any error in the question itself.
$\dfrac{1}{(x+1)} + \dfrac{1}{(x+5)}=\dfrac{1}{(x+2)}+\dfrac{1}{(x+4)}$.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Check the solution [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i={1%2F%28x%2B1%29}+%2B+{1%2F%28x%2B5%29}%3D{1%2F%28x%2B2%29}%2B{1%2F%28x%2B4%29}).

Answer (score 3):

$$
\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{1}{x+5}=\frac{1}{x+2}+\frac{1}{x+4}
$$
Notice that $x\ne\{-5,-4,-2,-1\}$.
$$
\frac{2x+6}{(x+1)(x+5)}=\frac{2x+6}{(x+2)(x+4)}
$$
One solution will be $2x+6=0\implies x=-3$.
Second solution will be
$$
(x+1)(x+5)=(x+2)(x+4)\\
x^2+6x+5=x^2+6x+8\\
$$
which gives you $5=8$, so only solution is $x=-3$.

Answer (score 1):

Your equation can be rewritten as
$$\frac{1}{x+5}-\frac{1}{x+4}=\frac{1}{x+2}-\frac{1}{x+1}$$
Or
$$\frac{1}{(x+4)(x+5)}=\frac{1}{(x+1)(x+2)}$$.
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{1}{(x+1)} + \dfrac{1}{(x+5)}=\dfrac{1}{(x+2)}+\dfrac{1}{(x+4)}$

$\implies \dfrac{1}{(x+5)}-\dfrac{1}{(x+4)}=\dfrac{1}{(x+2)}-\dfrac{1}{(x+1)} $

$\implies \dfrac{x+4-x-5}{(x+4)(x+5)}=\dfrac{x+1-x-2}{(x+1)(x+2)}$

$\implies (x+4)(x+5)=(x+1)(x+2)$

$\implies x^2+9x+20=x^2+3x+2$

$\implies 9x-3x+20-2=0$

Or,$$x=-3$$